# Getting SQL records and write into text file with tab separated delimeter in Java using apache-camel (except Spring and XML DSL file)

Tags: java, apache-camel

I need to get some records from oracle sql and write into a text file with tab separated delimeter in Java using apache-camel 
(except using Spring and XML DSL).
I am new to this framework and not able to understand how to start this.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know Apache Camel, it is worth to watch this first steps on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jZE-YSHK_gw

You need to use components to get from database, transform data and save into file. You can build your route using [SQL Component](http://camel.apache.org/sql-component.html) as your Consumer (put it into from() to start route). Then you need to transform message and save into a file (you can find examples for that two parts in a linked video).